# Passing enum types as parameters in java

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have two types of enums:

```
public static enum Type1 {
  T1_A,
  T1_B
}
```

and

```
public static enum Type2 {
  T2_A,
  T3_B
}
```

I want to be able to write an API which can take either of these enums (`Type1` or `Type2`) as parameters and do something with them. How can I design a method which let's me choose the Type of the enum during runtime?

Something to the effect of:

```
    void fun(?? type1_or_type2) {
         // something goes here...
    }
```

Comment: Why that downvote ?? question is quite clear. Atleast leave a comment.

Comment: How would you think it's possible to write a method that takes two different types? The answers below will undoubtedly "work" in that a common interface would allow passing anything that implements it, but the real question is "why would you want to do that?"

Comment: @BrianRoach That is what question is :) And we have  possible solutions too.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Often telling someone how to do something they shouldn't ... isn't useful.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a marker interface with no methods in it and let the enums implement that interface. Next, use the interface as the parameter type on your method.

Answer (score 3):

Define an interface, and implement that interface in you enum classes. Then use the Interface type as the parameter

```
interface Type {
    ...
}

public static enum Type1 implements Type {
  T1_A,
  T1_B
}

public static enum Type2 implements Type {
  T2_A,
  T2_B
}

void fun(Type aType) {
         // something goes here...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, this might be an approach to look at:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public void interface(Type1 type);
    public void interface(Type2 type);
}
```

Comment: potentially safer in the long run, avoiding someone implementing the interface suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    interface Marker {

    }

    enum Type1 implements Marker {
        T1_A, T1_B
    }

    enum Type2 implements Marker {
        T2_A, T3_B
    }


    void fun(Marker e) {
    // something goes here...
    if (e instanceof Type1) {
        // Do Type1 specific
    } else if (e instanceof Type2) {
        // Do Type2 specific
    }

   }
```

Comment: I definitely would want to avoid instanceof, especially if there are tons of enums to play with.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the Enum class as the parameter.

```
void fun(Class<? extends Enum<?>> yourEnum) {
    // Do something here. Here's how you would get an array of the Enum values.
    yourEnum.getEnumConstants();
}
```

You would pass Type1 in.

```
fun(Type1.class);
```